# problems with sending data - recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

good, I'm learning kotlin
I am wanting to send the data from one recyclerview to another recyclerview. By pressing a button, the name, price and photo, I want it to be sent to the other recyclerview and then another one and thus fill the list, what is the error?

**this is my code from my first recyclerview, which sends data, I am using bundle in the adapter to send it to the other recyclerview**

```
class Adaptador_Caras(private var caras: ArrayList<Caras>,private var context: Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptador_Caras.ViewHolder>() {

class  ViewHolder(var vista:View,var contexto:Context):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista){
    fun bind(caras:Caras){
        vista.ivFoto.setImageResource(caras.foto)
        vista.tvNombre.text=caras.nombre
        vista.tvPrecio.text=caras.precio.toString()

        vista.btnIngresar.setOnClickListener {

            val intent=Intent(contexto,RecyclerView::class.java)

            intent.putExtra("FOTO", caras.foto)
            intent.putExtra("NOMBRE",caras.nombre)
            intent.putExtra("PRECIO",caras.precio)

            contexto.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lista_caras,parent,false),context)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return caras.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(caras[position])
}
```

}

**this is the main activity, where the images are loaded**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    rvCaras.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvCaras.adapter=Adaptador_Caras(misCaras(),this)
}

private fun misCaras():ArrayList<Caras>{
    var caras=ArrayList<Caras>()
    caras.add(Caras("lucas",10,R.drawable.foto_01))
    caras.add(Caras("toluca",10,R.drawable.foto_02))
    caras.add(Caras("jiana",10,R.drawable.foto_03))
    caras.add(Caras("joina",10,R.drawable.foto_04))
    caras.add(Caras("toto",10,R.drawable.foto_05))
    return caras
}
```

}

**this is the adapter of the activity that receives the data**

```
class AdaptadorRecibir(private var recibir:ArrayList<Recibir>,private var context:Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorRecibir.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(var vista: View, var contexto:Context):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vista){
        fun bind(recibir: Recibir){

            vista.ivFotoR.setImageResource(recibir.fotoR)
            vista.tvNombreR.text=recibir.nombreR
            vista.tvPrecioR.text=recibir.precioR.toString()


        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lista_recibir,parent,false),context)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return recibir.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(recibir[position])
    }
}
```

**this is the activity receive data , here I receive the data**

```
class RecibirRecycler : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recibir_recycler)

    val parametros=this.intent.extras

    if (parametros!=null){
        val valor1=parametros.getInt("FOTO")
        val valor2=parametros.getString("NOMBRE")
        val valor3=parametros.getString("PRECIO")

        tvNombreR.text=valor2
        tvPrecioR.text=valor3
        ivFotoR.setImageResource(valor1)
    }
}
```

**thanks for your help**

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Send data with bundle

Inside `ViewHolder` class:

```
vista.btnIngresar.setOnClickListener {

startActivity(
            Intent(contexto, RecibirRecycler::class.java).putExtras(
            bundleOf(
                "FOTO" to (caras.foto?: 0),
                "NOMBRE" to (caras.nombre?:""),
                "PRECIO" to (caras.precio?:"))
        ))
    }
```